# How can I stock data, and send them over by serial?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I want to make an array with data from the sensor. In data, I have displacement in x/y axis. I want to send them in the array, because in my python code I don't send them one by one, slow down really quickly program.

**Arduino code responsible for sensor**

```
class MouseRptParser : public MouseReportParser
{
protected:
 void OnMouseMove (MOUSEINFO *mi);
};

void MouseRptParser::OnMouseMove(MOUSEINFO *mi)
{

    Serial.print(mi ->dX, DEC);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(mi ->dY, DEC);

};
```

I tried to do something on my own, but I get stuck with an error about data not in the scope. I try some variant placing it, but I don't succeed .

```
class MouseRptParser : public MouseReportParser {

 void OnMouseMove (MOUSEINFO *mi); };

void MouseRptParser::OnMouseMove(MOUSEINFO *mi)
{ int i;   for (i=0;i<10;i+2)   {
        data[i]=(mi ->dX, DEC);
        data[i+1]=(mi ->dY, DEC);   } 
  Serial.println(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7],data[8],data[9]);

    delay(20); };
```

EDIT:  I have now program that's making an array of 10 cells, but values in it are constatnt 10.

```
#include <hidboot.h>
#include <usbhub.h>

// Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#endif
#include <SPI.h>
int data[10];

class MouseRptParser : public MouseReportParser
{
protected:
 void OnMouseMove (MOUSEINFO *mi);
};

void MouseRptParser::OnMouseMove(MOUSEINFO *mi)
{

    for (int i=0; i<10; i=i+2)
  {
    data[i]=(mi->dX, DEC);
    data[i+1]=(mi->dY, DEC);

  }
  for(int j=0; j<10; j=j+1)
  {  
  Serial.print(data[j]);
  Serial.print(",");
}
Serial.println();
  delay(100);
};

USB     Usb;
USBHub     Hub(&Usb);
HIDBoot<USB_HID_PROTOCOL_MOUSE>    HidMouse(&Usb);

MouseRptParser Prs;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin( 9600 );
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
    while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
    //Serial.println("Start");

    if (Usb.Init() == -1)
        Serial.println("OSC did not start.");




    HidMouse.SetReportParser(0, &Prs);
}

void loop()
{


  Usb.Task();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "all at once" with serial. The whole point of serial is that it sends things one character at a time.

It is entirely up to you to decide what constitutes one "block" of data.

There is absolutely no difference (besides some slight processing overheads) between:

```
Serial.print("Hello");
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.println("World");
```

and:

```
Serial.println("Hello World");
```

Both of them result in Serial sending:

```
H
e
l
l
o
[space]
W
o
r
l
d
[cr]
[lf]
```

No matter how you "batch" stuff together (or attempt to) it makes no difference.

You need to have:

- Some way of identifying the *start* of a block of data,
- A mechanism to receive the entire block a byte at a time, and
- Some way of identifying the *end* of a block of data.

How you do that is entirely up to you.

---

Here's an example of how to arrange the storage:

```
class MouseRptParser : public MouseReportParser
{
    private:
        int dx[10];
        int dy[10];
        int dpos = 0;

    protected:
        void OnMouseMove (MOUSEINFO *mi) {
            dx[dpos] = mi->dX;
            dy[dpos] = mi->dY;
            dpos++;

            if (dpos == 10) {
                dpos = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Serial.print("X");
                    Serial.print(dx[i]);
                    Serial.print("Y");
                    Serial.print(dy[i]);
                }
                Serial.println();
            }
        }
};
```

What that gives you is a pair of 10-entry arrays, one for X and one for Y values. Each time a report arrives the current DX and DY values are stored. The pointer for where to store is incremented.  Then, if that pointer equals 10, reset it to 0 and print all the values.

I chose a format that gives you:

```
X3Y-2X2Y-4X6Y8X-3Y7X6Y38X176Y76X-4Y8X8Y3X39Y-32X71Y4
```

That is, an "X" followed by a decimal value for a change in X, and a Y followed by a decimal value for a change in Y. The whole lot is then terminated by a standard CR/LF line ending pair.

Comment: OK. I get it. I just need a a way to storage data, and send them over. I have now code to make an array of 10 elements and send them in loop, but its sending constant value. Check my edit post.

Comment: @Trzywu I don't think you are clear in your own mind exactly what you are trying to achieve. At the moment you take the X/Y coordinates and save them 5 times each in an array: `x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y`. Then you print those. What do you *actually* want to do? What data *do* you want to save? *When* do you want to send that data to the PC?

Comment: I want to send data in format like this x1,y1,x2,y2  and so on to x5,yy or x10,y10.  I want them send in some delay, i will figure out exact number when i get this portion of data.

Comment: So you want to store 5 coordinate pairs, and only when you have gathered 5 pairs do you want to send them to the PC. So you need to have some concept of how many pairs you have received, and only store the *current* pair in the *current* slots of the array. Only when the array is full do you do anything with Serial.

Comment: Please, can you be more specific?  I am reserving storage in this line"int data[10];" and  saving for respective cell here  " for (int i=0; i<10; i=i+2)
  {
    data[i]=(mi->dX, DEC);
    data[i+1]=(mi->dY, DEC);

  }"

Or am i missing something?

Comment: You are saving in *every* cell from 0 to 10. You do *not* want a `for` loop there. You just want some variable to say where in the array you *currently* are, and increment it only once for each report you receive. Only when the array is full (current == max) do you print the contents and reset the "current" pointer to the start of the array.

Comment: @Trzywu I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i was sleeping over.  I change some code to have specified character to split in.  Once again thank you very much.